# Find the sum to the $n^{th}$ term of the series

Tags: sequences-and-series

Find the sum of $n^{th}$ term of the series:
$$\frac{3}{1^2.2^2}+\frac{5}{2^2.3^2}+\frac{7}{3^2.4^2}+\cdots$$

I could not find the rule for the $n^{th}$ term.

Comment: Is it infinite or just $3$ terms as dots are missing?

Comment: @Archis, its infinite.

Comment: @Iaamuseruser If it is infinite, what do you mean by the $n^{th}$ term?

Comment: @GoodDeeds, I have typed the question as it is given.

Answer (score 1):

Let the $n^{th}$ of the corresponding sequence be $a_n$.
$$a_n=\frac{2n+1}{n^2(n+1)^2}=\frac1{n^2}-\frac1{(n+1)^2}$$
Thus, the sum $S_n$, telescopes and is

> $$S_n=1-\frac14+\frac14-\frac19+-\cdots+\frac1{n^2}-\frac1{(n+1)^2}=1-\frac1{(n+1)^2}$$